# Moving definite article to the end of a string in Python

Tags: python

Given the following strings as input to a Pythonic method:

> The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes
>
> The Art of War
>
> A Tale of Two Cities
>
> A Princess of Mars

I would like to see the following as the output:

> Adventures of Sherlock Holmes, The
>
> Art of War, The
>
> Tale of Two Cities, A
>
> Princess of Mars, A

Any ideas please?

Comment: Do you just want a function that fixes a single title, or do you want a function to transform the whole input? And, if the latter, is the input a list of strings, one big string with newlines, a text file, …? And are those blank lines in the input actually empty strings/lines that have to be left alone?

Comment: @abarnert I can do the actual implementation myself.  I just couldn't figure out  the actual code necessary.

Answer (score 2):

First, [`split`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) off the first word:

```
first, rest = title.split(None, 1)
```

Now, check if the first word is an article:

```
if first in {'A', 'An', 'The'}:
```

And, if so, move it to the end:

```
    return rest + ', ' + first
```

---

Putting it all together:

```
def fix_title(title):
    first, rest = title.split(None, 1)
    if first in {'A', 'An', 'The'}:
        return rest + ', ' + first
    return title
```

---

If you want to be able to handle blank lines properly, you need a bit more logic, and I think in this case it reads better with [`partition`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) instead of `split`. Just change the two lines in the middle to:

```
    first, _, rest = title.partition(' ')
    if first in {'A', 'An', 'The'} and rest:
```

Comment: I like this because it can handle times when there is no definite article in the string.

Comment: 'An' or 'A' is not a definite article

Comment: @Spaceghost: True, they're _indefinite_ articles. But that really belongs as a comment on the question; the OP clearly wants `'A'` and `'An'` to be moved, he just used the wrong wording in asking for it.

Comment: You are right.. I was responding after I saw it (again) in the comment .  I did not mean to suggest the answer was wrong.